# How Do I Extend a DataRow class

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nullable, datarow

I want to extend the System.Data.DataRow class, so I made the following code (and added the `using` keyword in my class)

```
namespace MyExtension
{
     public static class DataRowExt
      {
          public static string ToNullableDate(this DataRow dr)
          { return something;}
    }
}
```

However, when I try the following code, the `ToNullableDate` does not show up in Intellisense:

```
DataRow d = new DataRow();
d["Column"].ToNullableDate(); // ToNullableDate does not show up
```

Is there anything missing on my extension method statement? Or should I just create a new class and inherit from the DataRow class instead?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension method would be off, `d`, not off the indexer.

FYI, you can just do this:

```
DataRow d = new DataRow();
d["Column"] as DateTime?;
```

Comment: Okay, so can I extend the indexer then?

Comment: @Devmonster - it returns `Object`, but i wouldn't suggest extending that.

Comment: Yikes. Would you suggest that I inherit the DataRow class instead? Actually, my problem is that an external code returns a null value for the datetime value. My friend said declaring my variable as `DateTime?` still returns the exception 'Conversion from DBNull to other type'. Any recommended work arounds?

Comment: i've used the `as` operator to take care of it. it works for me.

Comment: Can you use this inside a Linq statement?

Comment: @Devmonster - can you ask that as a separate question? I would have to see the linq statement.

Answer (score 3):

Have you got `using MyExtension` in the code? Also, the extension is on DataRow, which is d, but you are looking for it on d["Column"].

From your comments it seems the value has null in it, and you need to test for that rather than create an extension...

```
 object value = d["Column"];
 if (value == DBNull.Value)
     // do something
 else
     // do something else
```

If you really want an extension method, one option is to pass the column in the method:

```
namespace MyExtension
{
   public static class DataRowExt
   {
       public static string ToNullableDate(this DataRow dr, string Column)
       { return something;}
   }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
d.ToNullableDate("Column");
```

Comment: Yes I have the `using` keyword in my class (mentioned in my post).
I guess my question would be how do I extend the d["Column] part.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. But, this is part of a Linq statement. So I need to check whether the datarow value is null or not. I am not yet experienced in Linq, and I don't know if there's a way to add `if` statements to Linq assignment

Comment: Thanks! That's what I did a while ago before I posted my question. This works too, but Daniel's suggestion works too.